# CakePHP 2.x Redirect all GETs(query) parameters

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to redirect all url's(like */index.php?start=16*, but also non-existent url's like */randomstring.php?something=test* - with query strings) to homepage '/' (in example google.com), after some reading I've been trying something like this in **app/Config/routes.php** (CakePHP 2).

```
Router::redirect('?', 'http://google.com', array('status' => 301));
```

and all possible variations with **/**, **\**,***** , with full url like "index.php?id=1", "\?id=1", everything - but it only working where there is no query string, like normal.
What I am doing wrong? I asked few friends, they also do not know how to do it.

Comment: Can you give some example urls that you want to redirect and the target? Also do you want the target url to receive the GET payload?

Comment: I want redirect url's like /index.php?start=16, but also non-existent url's like /randomstring.php?something=test (with query strings) to homepage ('/'), I do not need to receive the GET playload, just redirect all junk urls :)

Comment: Aren't all these url's already re-written to point to your index.php. Like most frameworks all requests are processed by the main app file. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html. Is it something else you are after?

Comment: No, they are not in the way I want, also with non-existent url I am getting errors, I want do 301 for all of them, not only for index.php, but for all urls and "files" like I wrote before. I want something like `if ($_GET) {redirect('/');}`

Comment: htaccess is fastest, but maybe this [dispatcher example](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim/blob/2.x/Routing/Filter/SeoDispatcher.php) can help you. You can also transform/catch any 404 exception and redirect then. But I wouldn't do that personally.

Comment: I will try this, thank you, can you tell more about query strings in .hta?